# Javascript - changing image position in game doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im a hobbyist html5 programmer with not that much of experience and im currently working on a game which requires me to have a moving player/image. The problem with the code below is that whenever I right-click the player only moves the first time and then never again. I've noticed that the interval is also not working and its only calling the function once. Also the xNum and yNum variables always remain 0 (noticed that as im console logging them each time the function is called). I dont know if i explained what i want the code to do well enough and sorry if i didnt. Go ahead and ask any questions you may have. Thank you for your time!

```
<html oncontextmenu="return false">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
#cursor{
    user-select: none;<!--disable highlighting of cursor-->
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<img src="images/test1.png" id = "player" style = "margin-left: 300px;margin-top: 100px;position: absolute;">
<img src="" id = "cursor" style = "visibility: hidden;">
<script>


document.getElementById('cursor').ondragstart = function () { return false;     };//disable dragging of cursor


window.onmousedown = function userClicked(event) {
    if(event.button == 2){
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
        cursor.src = "images/testCursorWalk.gif";
        cursor.style.visibility = "visible";
        cursor.style.position = 'absolute';
        cursor.style.left = x + 'px';
        cursor.style.top = y + 'px';
        setTimeout(function(){cursor.style.visibility = "hidden";cursor.src = "";},200)
        //after cursor is shown call player walk
        setInt(x,y);


    }
}




function setInt(x,y){
var xNum = 0;
var yNum = 0;
var walk = setInterval(walkPlayer(x,y,xNum,yNum),100);
}

function walkPlayer(x,y,xN,yN){
var p = document.getElementById("player");
var style = p.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(p);

    var ix = parseInt(style.marginLeft.substring(0,1));//get x
    var iy = parseInt(style.marginTop.substring(0,1));//get y
    var plx = document.getElementById("player").style.left;//method doesnt work
    var ply = document.getElementById("player").style.top;//method doesnt work
    var xNum = xN;
    var yNum = yN;

    //x-axis
    if(ix > x){
        xNum += 100;
        document.getElementById("player").style.left = xNum+'px';
    }
    else if(ix < x){
        xNum -= 100;
        document.getElementById("player").style.left = xNum+'px';
    }
    //y-axis
    if(iy > y){
        ply += 1000 +'px';//doesnt work with variables like ply
    }                     //...
    else if(iy < y){      //...
        ply -= 1000 +'px';//have to instead use the whole document.getElement...
    }

    if(iy == y && ix == x){
    alert("destination reached!")
        clearInterval(walk);//this wouldnt work as 'var walk' is private right?
    }



}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout and the mousedown event fire only once. You could use a setInterval to update the character continuously. Then you change the speed when the mouse is pressed or released.

```
let position = 0
let speed = 0
let cursor = document.getElementById("cursor")

function updatePosition(){
   position += speed
   cursor.style.left = position + 'px'
}

function startWalking(){
   cursor.src = "images/testCursorWalk.gif"
   this.speed = 5
}

function stopWalking(){
   cursor.src = "images/stop.gif"
   this.speed = 0
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", ()=> startWalking())
window.addEventListener("mouseup", ()=> stopWalking())
setInterval(()=>updatePosition(), 100)
```

Comment: That's actually not true :) see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMqoWE it's the setInterval that was wrong ... :)

Comment: Sorry that arrow representation confused me :) you're right

Comment: You were also right because this works too: `window.addEventListener("click", startWalking)`

Comment: Hello and thanks for helping. I'd like to say that i probably didnt explain what testCursorWalk.gif and test1.png are... So testCursorWalk is a animated pointer that shows where the user clicked and test1.png with "player" id is the for-now-static player image. Also i'd like to say i actually used a setInterval that updates the player position every 100ms and the interval is cleared when the destination is reached. So sadly i can't understand what you suggest both because i actually used a setInterval and because i confused you with the .png/.gif thing. Mind explaining to a newbie please? :)

Comment: Nevermind im working on another way of doing that (with html canvas) because i got really confuse with what i was trying to do.

Comment: In my answer an image starts moving as soon as you press the mouse, and it stops moving when you release the mouse. It’s a simpler and more readable way to achieve movement,  and it works in canvas as well!